# How to Intersect a variety of Polygons with lines?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS.

I have a certain numbers of areas (shp) and different channels (shp). Now i want to know how many meters of  the different channels are within the individual areas. the Intersect tool only allows to choose individual

[image]

[image]

Comment: Merge all the layers in each category, then intersect.

Comment: I allready tried this, as a result i get the the length of each channel but for the entire area

Comment: Then you're not doing it correctly, most likely you dissolved the polygons.

Comment: what i did is merge vector layer and I'm having all of attributes in the table. So I'm pretty sure that i did not dissolved them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my layer of polygons and lines.

[image]

Then you use the tool "sum of line lengths"

[image]

The result is a new polygonal layer (the same as the one at the entrance) but with 2 new fields: the first indicating the line length that crosses the polygon and the second field the number of lines that cross it.

[image]

Comment: Thx that works for me

Comment: With pleasure. In order to show that you have obtained a satisfactory answer, you can vote for my answer. See you later